# out parameters in c++ pass by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I want to achieve something similar in c++. This here is a c# code. I want to avoid raw pointers as much as possible.

```
class Program
{
    public class Foo
   {
        public int v1;
        public int v2; 
        public Foo(int a, int b)
        {
            v1 =a; v2 =b; 
        }
    };

    public class Bar
    {
        public static void getFoo(out Foo fooObj)
        {
            fooObj = new Foo(1,2);
        }
    };

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo fooObj = null; 
        Bar.getFoo(out fooObj);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo.v1="+fooObj.v1);
        Console.WriteLine("Foo.v2="+fooObj.v2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any C++ textbook or tutorial should explain how to use reference parameters.

Comment: @Barmar Few, if any, would explain the proper approach though (along the lines of Jose's answer).  Many would use raw pointers, or references to objects, which are quite far from being equivalent in function to the C# version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes my attempt to convert your C# code into C++. However, once you run it you need to do proper research on how to use use all the features I've used here. unique_ptr will basically manage the "raw" pointer for you (which is what you want, and it will free it once it goes out of scope). I've added an improved version using variadic templates so you can pass any number of arguments of any type to dynamically create your Foo class.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    int v1;
    int v2;

    Foo(int a, int b)
    {
        v1 =a; v2 =b;
    }
};

class Bar
{
public:
    // This is what your function looks like in C++
    static void getFoo(std::unique_ptr<Foo>& fooObj)
    {
        fooObj = std::make_unique<Foo>(1, 2);
    }

    // This is a better implementation.
    template<typename ...Args>
    static void getFoo_improved(std::unique_ptr<Foo>& fooObj, Args&&... args)
    {
        fooObj = std::make_unique<Foo>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // This is the one used more often in C++ tho.
    template<typename ...Args>
    static std::unique_ptr<Foo> getFoo_improved_x2(Args&&... args)
    {
        return std::make_unique<Foo>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> fooObj = nullptr; //nullptr is not needed tho
    Bar::getFoo(fooObj);

    std::unique_ptr<Foo> fooObj_alt = nullptr; //nullptr is not needed tho
    Bar::getFoo_improved(fooObj_alt, 9, 10);

    //This is as fast as the other two
    auto fooObj_alt_x2 = Bar::getFoo_improved_x2(50, 60);

    std::cout << "Foo.v1=" << fooObj->v1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Foo.v2=" << fooObj->v2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Foo_alt.v1=" << fooObj_alt->v1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Foo_alt.v2=" << fooObj_alt->v2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Foo_alt_x2.v1=" << fooObj_alt_x2->v1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Foo_alt_x2.v2=" << fooObj_alt_x2->v2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1, code only answer that doesn't explain anything and essentially just throws the code at the OP when they'd made no attempt

Comment: @Tas I wish someone told me where to look when I started in C++. Sometimes you just want to learn how to do something in a language, and you don't have the time to read 1000 pages of a book to do so.

Comment: `= nullptr;` is redundant on your declarations of `unique_ptr` objects ; they start off as empty. IMHO it makes the code more confusing.

Comment: note for OP: in C++ it is more usual style to have `getFoo` return `unique_ptr<Foo>` instead of taking a reference parameter.  Quite similar to how the `make_unique` function looks actually.

Comment: @M.M You are right, I've edited my answer to point out those facts. Altho the reason why I didn't do it the "proper" way from the start was to mimic his C# code, so he would understand it better.

Comment: I need to return an Error Code, so that is the reason I need to use a reference parameter. Sorry I didn't put that in the C# sample code. But thanks to Jose. The Answer is exactly what I wanted.